# Python Pandas: Create Dataframe Manually Where One Column Consists Row Lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to create a pandas data frame that looks as follows.

```
id  words
1   [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
1   [h, I, o]
1   
1   [a, b, c]
2   [e, f, g, m, n, q, r, s]
2   [w, j, f]
3   [l, t, m, n, q, s, a]
3   [c, d, e, f, g]
4   
4   [f, g, z]
```

I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'words': [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g], [h, I, o], '', [a, b, c], [e, f, g, m, n, q, r, s], [w, j, f], [l, t, m, n, q, s, a], [c, d, e, f, g], '',  [f, g, z]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Wrap your characters with single quotes `''`Use `['a', 'b']`..

Comment: that worked!  thank you :)